# What "?!?" in the dotnet-trace dump means

Tags: profiling

Does anyone know what "?!?" means in dotnet-trace speedscope dump? It wouldn't matter, but it takes a big CPU load. So I wonder what it can stand for

{ "name": "?!?" }

I searched for answer for a long time before decided to ask here and failed.